# How to connect to windows pptp vpn?

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, pptp

The VPN Server gave me an exe file - *connection manager* - to connect to the server.  Instead, I created a **pptp vpn connection** under **nm-applet**, entering only ***Host, Username & password***.
Later I figured out there were more options that needed to be set. I extracted the .exe file contents, and found a .cms file with some options that looked relevant, but I didn't know how to set them under Ubuntu.

Here is the file content http://pastebin.com/FmgkFBcS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may only be missing the actual encryption method, which seems to be specified in the

> [Server&PPTP  2.8]

and

> [Server&PPTP  2.8 Tunnel]

blocks from your example. This should roughly translate to the Advanced window in nm-applet's PPTP VPN configuration:

[image: PPTP Advanced Options]

I'd suggest first trying to enable MPPE and keeping all other options as default (so that it enabled MPPE, which offers encryption, and MSCHAP-type authentication methods, which are enabled in your example for the PPTP 2.8 section). If it doesn't work, disable all the authentication options but PAP, so that things would equate to about the same as the "PPTP 2.8 Tunnel" section in your example.

If it's any use, there is now a bug open on Launchpad about supporting the import of CMS-type configuration in NetworkManager: [bug 711282](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/711282)

Comment: I didn't test MPPE, but disabling all authentication methods but PAP solved the problem. I will check MPPE and report it here. thanks Mathieu.

Comment: I tested MPPE but it gives me authentication error!

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft documentation, the cms file is a `Service provider` file that `specify the configuration of the phone book and most of the other functions of your service profiles. Most advanced customization for a service profile is done by editing the .cms file for that service profile.`

I couldn't find any Linux or Ubuntu documentation about cms files specifically, I couldn't even find any Microsoft documentation about what the format should contain. Looking at it though, it does appear as if it contains a bunch of options which match up to the advanced options in the network manager vpn creation dialog.

I couldn't match all of them, I don't know what connection type is. But further research should provide the answer.